# Login form: the value of user is always equal to 0 instead of a typed string

Tags: php, html

I have a login form with two fields: user and password. For some reason, the value of `user` is always equal to `0`, while the value of `pass` is passed correctly. I can see it using echo: `<h1>User:<?php echo $user ?>Pass:<?php echo $pass ?></h1>`

I was revising the code, but cannot understand why does it happen. Why `user` is not captured correctly?

```
<?php
    @session_start();
    $error = 0;
    if (isset($_POST["user"]) && isset($_POST["pass"])) {

        include_once 'include/User.php';

        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        $error = 0;

        $user = User::checkLogin($user, $pass);

        if(!is_object($user) && $user == 0){
            $error = 1;
            if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
                session_unset();
                session_destroy();
            }
        }

        if($error == 0){
            $_SESSION['loged'] = 1;
            $login = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $user->id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user->name." ".$user->surename;
            header("Location: index.php?pagina=1");
        }
        else{
            $error = 1;
            if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
                session_unset();
                session_destroy();
            }
        }
    }
?>
<div class="form_login">

    <form action="index.php?pagina=0" method="POST">
        <div class="form_login_line">
            <div class="form_login_txt">
                Username:
            </div>
            <div class="form_login_input">
                <input type="text" name="user" id="user" size="10" value="user"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form_login_line">
            <div class="form_login_txt">
                Password:
            </div>
            <div class="form_login_input">
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size="10" value="pass"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form_login_line">
            <div class="form_login_submit">
                <input id="input_login_error" type="button" value="Login" onclick="submitForm()"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div id="login_error">The username or password are incorrect or don't have access permissions.<h1>User:<?php echo $user ?>Pass:<?php echo $pass ?></h1></div>

</div>
<?php if($error == 1): ?>
    <script>$("#login_error").show();</script>
<?php endif;?>
<script>
    page_name("Login");

    function submitForm(){
        //$("#pass").val(sha1($("#pass").val()));
        $('form').prepend('<input type="submit" id="submit5548" style="display: none"/>');
        $("#submit5548").click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using js to submit the form when you are just submitting it on the same page?

Comment: `$user->surename` looks like a typo to me which should probably read as `$user->username`, I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you overwrite $user with User::checkLogin.

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$error = 0;
$user = User::checkLogin($user, $pass);
```

My advise is to use an IDE, they notify you about this stuff. For example, I use Netbeans for PHP development and it always notifies me about an "accidental assignment" of a variable, here it would've stated the same to you.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at that also. Am just not sure about their `$user->surename` though; seems like a probable typo.

Comment: Yeah could be a typo, then again his class might actually have that parameter (he doesn't seem to be natively english, so he might have mistakes).

Comment: The letters for `surename` can also spell out `username` - they both contain the same letters once rearranged ;-) I made a comment under their question about that probable typo.

Comment: Could be right indeed. Then again, shouldn't an error pop up if the method/variable is not accessible? edit: it might not if you don't got error_reporting(E_ALL) set.

Comment: Only if they're checking for errors. I just wanted to make sure since like I said, theoretically one would think/write/use the word "username" for a *ahem* "username" ;-) But as I said in that comment I left under their question, I could be wrong about it; I just like to make sure they didn't make a typo. Sometimes our fingers work faster than our minds.

Comment: True that. Will see what his response is! ;)

Comment: ..just to throw in another guess: 'surename' also could be a (phonetic) missspelling of 'sirname'...